# Ability to select a song followed by shuffle mode of the entire library

Tags: zune-player

Right now if I pick a song manually, the remaining songs that will be played are all by the same artist. Is there a way that I can pick the first song then have it shuffle through my collection?

EDIT: This is for the Zune app on Windows Phone 7.5

Comment: Are you referring to the standalone Zune media player app on your pc? That would not really be on topic as defined by the faq, unless you are referring to playing your collection while your phone is synced to your pc. If it is the latter, could you please edit your question to be more specific :)

Comment: I actually meant the zune app on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understand, Zune is a sort of package or stack for media applications. For playing music, you need to launch the **music** app inside the zune.

YES, in music there is a way to do the task mentioned in your question. All you need to do is just go into the **music** app, slide to **songs** and choose the first song you want to play. Now, when the song window appears and the song starts playing, you can tap on the **shuffle** icon which is next to album art and just below the **like** icon.

This way you can choose the first song and then shuffle them all.

:-)

Comment: I only ever pick my music manually though the artist page. Wish I could do what I want through that, but your method works too.

Comment: I guess the artist page have auto-lists for all artists individually. Hence, achieving the task through that isn't possible in any platform including iOS and android.